# How to extract text between multiple delimiters in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

| Original Text | What I want |
| --- | --- |
| xxxa - Long Shirt - White - S | Long Shirt - White |
| xxxb - Long Shirt - White Gold - M | Long Shirt - White Gold |
| xxxxc - Pants - Gold - 31 | Pants - Gold |
| xxxd - High Leather Shoes - 07 | High Leather Shoes |
| xxd - Other Materials | Other Materials |

The above is the sample data. I want to extract the text between the first "-" and the last "-" as I have described in the "What I want" column.

The formula that I used is this:
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(K132, FIND("-", K132) + 1, FIND("-", K132, FIND("-", K132) + 1) - FIND("-", K132) - 1), "-", "", 1) & "-" & SUBSTITUTE(MID(K132, FIND("-", K132, FIND("-", K132) + 1) + 1, FIND("-", K132, FIND("-", K132, FIND("-", K132) + 1) + 1) - FIND("-", K132, FIND("-", K132) + 1) - 1), "-", "", 1)

However, it doesn't work for the last two rows. How can I edit it?

Comment: Why not use Text To Columns, delimited by `-`, and then scrub the columns you don't want?

Comment: Because I want the data to be automated. If i use Text to columns, I have to go manually edit every time, which is multiple times per day. If I can figure out the formula, I can just update the data and automatically get the extracted texts.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add requested information or clarification to your question. Please add some background information. Where does the data come from? How do you get it into Excel? What do you want to do with the result? There might be other tools to do the expected modification.

Comment: Please edit you question to make it clearer what you want to achieve.  You said you want to extract the text between the first "-" and the last "-" , but in the last example that would mean an empty string, as there is only one.

Comment: @Kelvinlin Also, are you using Excel 365? That version has some useful options that earlier versions don't have.

Comment: I know you're after an automated version, but wanted to get my tuppence in - if you manually type in the first entry of what you want, go to the next cell down and press _Ctrl+E_ it flash fills the rest for you.  Doesn't work on the last one though - that just returns "Other".

Answer (score 2):

If you have `365`, 
and what you want is to return the text between the first and last hyphens
or just after the first if there is no last hyphen
then:

```
=LET(
    first, TEXTAFTER(A2, "-", 1, , , A2),
    last, TEXTBEFORE(first, "-", -1, , , first),
    TRIM(last)
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This formula will work for Excel 365:

```
=MID(K132,FIND("-",K132)+1,IF(LEN(K132)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(K132,"-",""))>1,LEN(K132)-FIND("-",K132)-FIND("-",CONCAT(MID(K132,SEQUENCE(LEN(K132),,LEN(K132),-1),1))),LEN(K132)))
```

Explanation:

`=MID(K132,FIND("-",K132)+1,`  -- start just after the first "-"

`IF(LEN(K132)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(K132,"-",""))>1,`  -- if there is more than one "-"in the string

`LEN(K132)-FIND("-",K132)-`  -- then extract the number of characters between first "-"...

`FIND("-",CONCAT(MID(K132,SEQUENCE(LEN(K132),,LEN(K132),-1),1)))` -- and the last "-", found by reversing the string using a dynamic array

`,LEN(K132)))` -- otherwise, simply extract all remaining characters